# Trying to put java code into Eclipse, to make android app?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Ok so I am being bombarded with a bunch of little red x's. I am using the eclipse program to create an Android application.
There are 2 main files im using. Java and XML.

Now when I am making the Android appplication, I have an XML file with all of the text boxes, buttons, etc. in it.

The problem is my java code is written to receive and print out into a command prompt. How can I implement this into the app/XML file, to make everything print out into certain text boxes,and receive user input(the scanner) from the text boxes inside the actual app?
Thank you very much, im brand new at programming and have been learning java but haven't discovered how to use it.

This is a code to convert the date into the Julian day. Everything works fine.
Here is my Java file:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class joe {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner jim = new Scanner(System.in);
        int month, day;
        int answer;
        System.out.println("Enter month: ");
        month = jim.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter day");
        day = jim.nextInt();

        if (month == 1){
            answer = (0 + day);
            System.out.println(answer);

        }else if (month == 2){
            answer = (31 + day);
            System.out.println(answer);

        }else if (month == 3){
            answer = (59 + day);
            System.out.println(answer); 

        }else if (month == 4){
            answer = (90 + day);
            System.out.println(answer);

        }else if (month == 5){
            answer = (120 + day);
            System.out.println(answer);

        }else if (month == 6){
            answer = (151 + day);
            System.out.println(answer);

        }else if (month == 7){
            answer = (181 + day);
            System.out.println(answer);

        }else if (month == 8){
            answer = (212 + day);
            System.out.println(answer);

        }else if (month == 9){
            answer = (243 + day);
            System.out.println(answer);

        }else if (month == 10){
            answer = (273 + day);
            System.out.println(answer);

        }else if (month == 11){
            answer = (304 + day);
            System.out.println(answer);

        }else if (month == 12){
            answer = (334 + day);
            System.out.println(answer);



        }
    }
}
```

and here is my XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.change.juliandayconverter.MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/_4_25_2015"
        android:inputType="date" >

        <requestFocus android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="none|number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:text="Please enter the date above"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Google stopped the support for the android plugin for eclipse. Why don't you use Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Get the **ADT plugin** for Eclipse, and then download the **SDK for Android**. Then in Eclipse Window=>preference=> choose the path for SDK and then u are ready to start a Android Application. Project=>new=>New Android Application project. Then there is a bunch of other things to know as well. So without ADT and SDK u cannot make an APP for Android.

If u dont like Eclipse and ADT go for **Android Studio**.
A small program that gets a data and displays the same. This might help you.

MainActivity class:

```
package com.dj.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tvRes;
    EditText etData;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initializing the edit text using id  in xml file(stored in R.java class).
        etData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editData);
        //initializing the text view using id given in xml file(stored in R.java class).
        tvRes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdisplay);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void display(View v){

        //When the button is clicked fetch the data from edit text and display it on the text view

        tvRes.setText(etData.getText().toString());

    }
}


xml:

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.dj.test.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvdisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvdisplay"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
       android:hint="Enter your name">


        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:onClick="display"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. stop using eclipse use android studio from now becuse google stop the support for the Eclipse
2. you need